# R - Averaging rows that have the same name

Tags: r, average

Very new to R.

I have a simple data set with two columns : name and length. The data I have shows some names that have two occurrences. How do I average these lengths and then only list 1 name with the averaged length instead of the 2? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a couple of approaches:

-With base R:

```
aggregate(length~name,d,mean)
#   name length
# 1    a    5.0
# 2    b    8.5
# 3    c    7.0
```

-With the `dplyr` package (definitely worth spending time to explore)

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(avg=mean(length))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
# name avg
# 1    a 5.0
# 2    b 8.5
# 3    c 7.0
```

Sample reproducible data set could be produced by these commands:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(name=sample(letters[1:3],size=5,replace=TRUE),length=sample(10,size=5,replace=TRUE))

#   name length
# 1    a      9
# 2    b     10
# 3    b      7
# 4    c      7
# 5    a      1
```

Answer (score 3):

And how about an original solution with a linear fit! in just one line:

```
    lm(length ~ name - 1, df)$coef
### namea nameb namec 
###   5.0   8.5   7.0
```

Comment: this approach has the advantage of not needing the na.rm argument

Comment: And the disadvantage of silently dropping NAs.

Comment: exactly. But it's a disadvantage only if you're not aware of it, that's why I mention it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table` (data from @Marat Talipov's post)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, list(length=mean(length)), name][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the R way or the best way but you could do

```
library(sqldf)
df <- howeveryougetyourdata.csv
sqldf('SELECT AVG(length) average_length FROM df WHERE name IN ("this","that"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to calculate the mean length for each name.  I'd tackle it like this.

```
library(plyr)
df.new <- ddply(df, .(name), summarise, length=mean(length))
```

Given you're new to R, I encourage you to take the time to learn some of Hadley Wickham's packages `plyr` (or `dplyr`), `reshape2` and `ggplot2`. They're specifically designed to make lots of these data operations more intuitive than base R.